# How to write an if condition when right hand side involves an awk variable?

Tags: bash, awk

Let's say I have a field that indicates date in `yyyymmdd` format and I want to filter rows greater than a given value for that field.

If I use the following `if` condition inside my `awk` statement, it works just fine

```
if ($1> "20200315")
```

But let's say I define 2020 as `yyyy` and 03 as `mm`, then pass these variables in as `awk -v ym=${yyyy}${mm}`

How should my `if` condition in the `awk` statement look like? I tried the following, but it's not filtering any rows.

```
if ($1> "ym15")
```

Comment: Remove the quotes?

Comment: It should be `if ($1 > ym "15")`

Comment: Holy cow! That seems so obvious now. Thank you!

Comment: Don't even need quotes, just the sapce to concatentate: `if ($1 > ym 15)`

Comment: @EricBolinger without the quotes it'd fail if the final number was `05` instead of `15` since `05` would be converted to just `5` before the concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was `"ym15"` because when within quotes, `awk` doesn't treat `ym` as a variable. Based on the comments, solution was to  unquote the variable and only quote the adjacent string "15".

```
if ($1 > (ym"15"))
```

Comment: You might want to make that `if ($1 > (ym 15))` so it's clear to anyone reading your code (and to the awk interpreter!) that that is what you mean rather than `if (($1 > ym) 15)`. You should use the quotes around `15` though (i.e. `"15"`) as you want it treated as a string, not a number. What you have now would fail if the date was `05` instead of `15` as the concatenation of `202003` and `05` (no quotes) would end up `2020035` instead of `20200305`. So the clear, robust code would be `if ($1 > (ym "15"))`.